# Dialog fragment in alarm manager in android,its not working

Tags: android

```
public  class MainActivity extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}}
```

Comment: here "set content view " and "time picker fragment" is marked red.moreover, i am unable to debug my app(i am testing code on my phone,message shown upon debugging is host target connected but dont know what to do after that...nothing going right)

Comment: You should rename this class. Calling it an Activity when it does not extend Activity is needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 3):

In `DialogFragment` you must use `onCreateView` not `setContentView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,
            false);

    return view;
}
```

and for `TimePickerFragment` you call with `TimePickerFragment.newInstance()` and make `newInstance` Constructor required in `DialogFragment`

```
        DialogFragment dialogFrag = null;
        dialogFrag = TimePickerFragment.newInstance();
        dialogFrag.setTargetFragment(this, request_id);
        dialogFrag.show(getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(),
                "timepicker_dialog");
```